# Team site background color, web part design?

Tags: web-part, design

Is it possible to change the background color of a team site, and a web part as well? are we able to design a web part with rounded corner fx?

Comment: Can we make the promoted link image bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes we need to override the css having the background color and u will be able to change the color.

Comment: okay thank you for the answer. What about the web parts, can we make them more elegant in any way?

Comment: Promoted links? can we make the images bigger in px or likewise?

Comment: yes....add a content editor webpart and override the css class associated with the promoted links.. in the custom css class you can have your size pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The background color of the sites can be changed via CSS. In case you don't want to write your custom CSS, you can also apply any of the in-built themes to your SharePoint sites. Theme can be changed using following steps:

- Go To Site Settings -> Change the Look (Under Look and Feel Section)
- Select any of the available theme on the page, change the colors, images etc. based on your requirement and click on Try it Out to see a preview.

  - If you like the preview, then click on Yes, Keep it and your site would acquire the new theme.

The corners of a web part can be made rounded using a CSS property called:

```
border-radius:<<Pixel Units here>>
```